# how to instrument java code hosted in aws ecs instance and aws lambda with context propogation using opentelemetry

Tags: dashboard, trace, instrumentation, open-telemetry, observability

I want to instrument my java code hosted in aws ecs instance (producer) and aws lambda (consumer) with context propagation using opentelemetry.

Tried auto instrumentation which works fine for the producer and consumer as a seperate entity, there is no continuity of trace from producer till consumer